# File Download Portlet in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i am new to this Liferay.Can any one help me in creating a portlet for downloading a File?I just added some files using Document and Media .My intention is to create a portlet for downloading files.

Comment: There is already document library display portlet for downloading the files. If you have particular requirement you can go through Document Library Display Portlet jsps to understand how it works.

Comment: Where can i find the Document Library Display Portlet?

Comment: create a page, add a portlet to the page. In the list of available portlets you'll find "Documents and Media Display" in the "Content Management" section. Configure it to show the folder that you want to show.

Comment: @Dhanya what i guess is that you want to make a custom portlet for downloading  let me know

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to develop a portlet similar to our Documenta and Media Display Portlet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a portlet smililar to document and media portlet then.. Its better you start your development and then start getting suggestions.. Still Let me give You an Overview.

1. Understand Existing database Mechanism
2. Understand Service classes and wrappers
3. Understand existing permission for Documents and Media
4. Start development